# C void pointers and pointer comparison

Tags: c, pointers, struct, comparison, void-pointers

I have the following function to remove generic data from a linked list in C:

```
void removeData(void *data, struct accList *theList)
{
    struct accListNode* cur = theList->head;
    struct accListNode* prev = NULL;

    for(; cur != NULL; prev = cur, cur = cur->next)
    {
        if(cur->data == data)
        {
            if(cur == theList->head)
            {
               theList->head = cur->next;
            }
            if(cur == theList->tail)
            {
                theList->tail = prev;
            }
            if(prev != NULL)
            {
                prev->next = cur->next;
            }
            free(cur);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the meaning behind `cur->data == data`?

Since my data is generic (`void*`), what does this mean for any primitive type and any structure type?

For example, consider the employee structure:

```
struct employee
{
    char name[20];
    float wageRate;
};
```

How would the statement `cur->data == data` work if data is of type `struct employee*`?
Since data is a pointer to the first memory address of the structure am I just comparing pointer addresses?

Comment: You're not comparing pointer addresses (e.g. `&data`), you're comparing the pointers, which are addresses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cur->data == data
```

Compares the pointer `cur->data` to the pointer `data`.  You're comparing their values, not their addresses.  A pointer is a variable like any other.  It has an address (i.e., `&some_ptr`) and a value (i.e., the address of the thing it refers to).

Note that other types of comparisons (i.e., `<` `>` `>=` `<=`) result in undefined behavior unless the pointers point to elements of the same array or one past the end (not that it would make sense to do so unless you knew they pointed to "objects" that resided in the same chunk of contiguous memory anyway, but still).

Comment: So I am comparing the addresses of the values pointed to by cur->data and data?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: Yes, and those addresses are the value of the pointers.  The pointers themselves still require memory to store, so they have their own address, but `some_ptr` and `&some_ptr` are not equivalent.

Comment: I want to compare the values of the generic data. Is this really possible? It seems like I would have to add an extra parameter where the caller would have to supply a pointer to a function that defines the equality of the generic type. Does this seem right?

Comment: @Jack: Equality comparison is valid, other comparisons (i.e., `<` `>`) results in undefined behavior unless  the pointers point to elements of the same array object or one past the end.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the meaning behind cur->data == data?

The code is checking is both pointers are the same pointer

> Since my data is generic (void*) what does this mean for any primitive
>   type and any structure type?
>
> How would the statement cur->data == data work if data is of type
>   struct employee*?

Nothing, the comparison works the same

> Since data is a pointer to the first memory address of the structure
>   am I just comparing pointer addresses?

Nope, you're comparing pointers

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Yes, they are just addresses, in fact, they are variables which content are addresses

Comment: What I want is to compare the "values" of these pointers. It seems like I would have to add an extra parameter to my function so the caller could supply a pointer to a function describing "equality" of this generic type. Does this seem right?

Comment: Do you want to check if both `cur->data` and `data` has equal values (so they could be different "objects" but with equal values) or if they are the same variable?. In the first case, your solution should work and it's a pretty valid one, in the second case, comparing both addresses should work because both pointers would be referring to the same "object"

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the pointers thermself, not the struct pointed to.

Comment: These pointers are just addresses though right? So my comparison is not good for anything

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus well, that depends on whether you got the pointer from the list in the first place or just want to remove anything identical to the thing pointed to. Most likely it would be the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing that you didn’t write removeData()?  If not, then my explanation is:

removeData() is designed to remove a specific entry (i.e. *data) from the linked list, not an entry whose content equals *data.  So a caller of removeData() has to already know exactly where the entry is that they want free()’ed.  They could free() it themselves, but that wouldn’t be nice because the linked list still contains a pointer to it, and presumably other users of the linked list would think the free()’ed object was still valid (they would have no reason to believe otherwise, absent any other scheme of telling them such).

If you want a function that searches theList for an entry whose content matches the content of *data (but is not at the same memory as *data), then you’ll need to write a version of removeData() for each such type, and your accList will either need to be homogeneous (containing all objects of that type), or else accList will need to also contain some indication of each entry’s type, perhaps as an enum, and each version of removeData() (one for each type) will need to skip elements that don’t match its own type.